# Update A Hidden FIeld Using Prototype

Tags: prototype

I'm trying to update the value of a hidden form field using Prototype. The form field:

```
<input id="item_id" name="item_id" value="" type="hidden" />
```

I'm trying to update the value like so using prototype:

```
var additionalVal = ',2';
var itemId = $$('name=["itemid"]');
itemId.value = (itemId.value + ',' + additionalVal);
```

The element appears to be updated and if I query it using the web inspector, the value has been updated. However, if I look at the hidden field, it still looks like this:

```
<input id="item_id" name="item_id" value="" type="hidden" />
```

... an empty value field. Also, submitting it like this enters a null column into the table. Without including my whole JS file (450 lines), can anyone give me a pointer to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo in the name of the field (itemid instead of item_id). The `$$` function in prototype returns an array of elements. You must get the first element of the array to change its value :

```
var additionalVal = ',2';
var itemId = $$('name=["item_id"]');
itemId[0].value = (itemId[0].value + ',' + additionalVal);
```

You can also get the element by its `id`, so you will not need get the first item :

```
var additionalVal = ',2';
var itemId = $('item_id');
itemId.value = (itemId.value + ',' + additionalVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

By updating a value to the field by using prototype. You can use this code.

```
$('Id of the element').setValue('value')
```